# Supremum inequality over a seperable space

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, supremum-and-infimum

I need some help by understanding the following:

Suppose that $\mathcal{F} = \{f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R} \; measurable\}$ is seperable and $P$ is some probability measure. Then it holds that:
$\sup\limits_{f \in \mathcal{F}} P(f) \leq \sup\limits_{S \subset \mathcal{F} countable} P(\sup\limits_{f \in S} f). $

My questions:

1. Does the following equality hold?
   $\sup\limits_{f \in \mathcal{F}} f = \sup\limits_{S \subset \mathcal{F} countable} \sup\limits_{f \in S} f.$
   If so, why is the above inequality not an equality? If not, why isn't it an equality?
2. Why can I put the supremum in front of the measure $P$? Can I do this every time or do I need some conditions on $P$ to do that?
3. I think the inequality has something to do with the fact, that (since $\mathcal{F}$ is seperable) there exists some countable and dense subset $S \subset \mathcal{F}$ such that $\bar{S} = \mathcal{F}$ (here $\bar{S}$ denotes the closure of $S$). Is that true?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq) to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!

Comment: What is the topology on $\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: sorry for not mention it, we're on a borel space, so we're on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$, where $\mathcal{A}$ describes the borel sigma algebra and $\Omega \subset \R^d$ not empty.